# JavaScript loadWithAjax on skip links

Tags: javascript, ajax

How do I stop the error loadWithAjax is not defined when using the following script?

```
addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    if (ev.target.classList.contains('bpb')) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        loadWithAjax(ev.target.href);
    }   
});
```

This is to stop skip links appending the #xxx to the URL. There may be a better way, but, I don't know one :-)

```
<div id="access" role="region" aria-label="Skip links">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a class="bpb" href="#navigation">Skip to primary navigation</a></li>
            <li><a class="bpb" href="#chapter-content">Skip to main content</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: have you defined your loadwithAjax function?

Comment: No. I don't know how :-(

Comment: you need to declare that function like so: `function loadWithAjax(){}`

Comment: So what exactly you want to happen when the click is done? Why are you calling an ajax method?

Comment: Thanks Josan. Dreamhigh I am calling the class to stop # being appended to the URL when the link is activated. Bypass blocks linking to ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Josan's answer worked.

you need to declare that function like so: function loadWithAjax(){}